# Jest React-native How to mock a function and return a response

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I am new to Jest unit testing.

I want to test a component that **makes multiple calls** to the [Geolocation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html) getCurrentPosition() method.

**For each call to the function I want to return a new coordinate object.**

I have read various articles and tutorials but I am still struggling.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the navigator object using `global.navigator`. So to mock `getCurrentPosition` just assign a `jest.fn` to it:

```
global.navigator = {
  getCurrentPosition : jest.fn()
}
```

So how to return new coordinates for every call. The easiest solution would be a global counter

```
const coords = [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
let counter = -1
global.navigator = {
  getCurrentPosition: jest.fn(() {
    counter++
    return coords[counter]
  })
}
```

Or you could use the `calls` property of the mock

```
const coords = [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
global.navigator = {
  getCurrentPosition: jest.fn(() =>
    coords[global.navigator.getCurrentPosition.mock.calls.length]
  )
}
```

Comment: I tried adding this to my jest test file, but I was getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentPosition' of undefined`.  I changed `global.navigator` to `global.navigator.geolocation`, and now my test is passing.  Disclaimer: I am very new to react native and jest at the time of writing this.